# Generate location agnostic cross toolchain

Tags: cross-compilation, toolchain

I've built a cross-compiler for an ARM Cortex-A8 using crosstool-ng, but I'm running into some problems when trying to compile even the simplest of programs.

Trying to compile `test.h`:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o prog test.c
test.c:1:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I generated the toolchain in a specific directory, then copied it to another folder on my home dir. This toolchain is supposed to be used by others to develop an application, so I moved it  to a more 'sensible' path.

Afterwards, I tried to compile the same code using the toolchain directly from the path it was originally generated, and it works. I suspected this had something to do with the path to the target's sysroot, but after checking with `--print-sysroot`, it seems that both paths are consistent with the current location of the toolchain binaries. (Note: I added the path for the copied toolchain to my `$PATH`, before any other directory)

```
$ /home/guilherme/Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --print-sysroot # Copy
/home/guilherme/Toolchain/bin/../arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot

$ /home/guilherme/Development/toolchain/tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --print-sysroot # Original
/home/guilherme/Development/toolchain/tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot
```

Any help with this problem?  Is there any option in ct-gn allowing me to create a toolchain that can be moved/copied to other folders/machines?

Comment: An update: it seems that the problems occurs when I run `make headers_install`  to copy the kernel headers to the toolchain's sysroot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

I was using `make headers_install ARCH=arm HDR_INSTALL_PATH=${TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT}/usr` to update the toochain headers. However, this copies a few (not all) headers from `${KERNEL_PATH}/include/linux` to `${TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT}/usr` 'sanitizing' any headers besides the ones copied, thus deleting stdio.h, math.h and other "unimportant" headers.